# Подмена и/или отмена нажатия клавиши WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Использую глобальный хук *WM_KEYBOARD_LL*, для отлова сообщений о нажатых клавишах. Как при нажатии определённой клавиши отменить её действие, а лучше, переназначить его? Пример: нажали NUM PAD 5, получили 'n'. Иными словами, программное переназначение клавиши.
P.S.: пробовал  *WH_GETMESSAGE*, но он ловит только сообщения текущей программы.
P.S.S.: пробовал отменить так,но не получилось:

```
keybd_event(key, NULL, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отмены нажатия клавиши, функция LowLevelKeyboardProc должна вернуть ненулевое значение. Чтобы сгенерировать свое событие нажатие клавиши, можно использовать SendInput

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* details = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;
    INPUT ip;

    if(code == HC_ACTION && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        if(details->vkCode == code)
        {
            ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            ip.ki.time = 0;
            ip.ki.wVk = new_code; 
            ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; 
            SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;     
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! 
Функцию SendInput использовал, она пришла на замену ведь keybd_event. Но, я напортачил в коде, и функция срабатывала неверно..а вот про возвращённое значение огромное спасибо вдвойне! Про это не знал.